# Fill header with background colour

Tags: css, html, margin, padding, background-color

I currently have a heading 1 and logo on the same line of the header, and now I want to have a background colour for the header. I would ideally want this to come down below the nav bar as well.
The issue I'm having is that the colour doesnt fill the top part of the page as I thought it would. It only covers the heading and it also covers the logo on the same line.

How would I stop the colour from going over the image and how would I make the colour spread from the top of the page to below the nav bar.

HTML:

```css
.header img {
  float: left;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  padding-left: 40%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.nav{
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  height: 40px;
  width: 19.925%;
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.nav li:last-child{
border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>The Clay Oven Pizzeria</title>
</head>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/pizzalogo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
      <h1> The Clay Oven Pizzeria</h1>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#index"> Home </li>
        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</li>
        <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</li>
        <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: This is what I mean about the background colour covering the logo:
[image]

Comment: could you provide the screenshot of what you want?

Comment: why are you add <header> tag before <body> tag?

Comment: @ManishPatel Isn't that what you're supposed to do?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Done.

Comment: @DanielLawton that was invalid html you need to add <header> tag in body   tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped the HTML header tag to be within the body. Your body tag is where it will house all your html minus the head tag that has your title. Not a big deal since it renders fine, just a best practice. I also changed the css for your header img to have a z-index which places the image on top of the h1 tag and your h1 tag to have a z-index of -100 to always fall to the back.

Hope this helps.

```css
.header img {
  float: left;
  background: #555;
  z-index: 100; /* added */
  width: 100px; /* added */
}

.header h1 {
  z-index: -1; /* added */
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  padding-left: 40%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.nav{
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  height: 40px;
  width: 19.925%;
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.nav li:last-child{
border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>The Clay Oven Pizzeria</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/28083349/Pick-a-Pizza-Logo-of-your-Own.jpg" 
       alt="logo"/>
      <h1> The Clay Oven Pizzeria</h1>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#index"> Home </li>
        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</li>
        <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</li>
        <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .header img {
  float: left;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  padding-left: 40%;

}

.nav{
 width: 95%;
 margin: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: inline;
 height: 40px;
 width: 19.925%;
    float: left;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.nav li:last-child{
 border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>The Clay Oven Pizzeria</title>
 </head>
 <header style="  background-color:#D3D3D3;">
  <div class="header" >
   <img src="images/pizzalogo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
   <h1> The Clay Oven Pizzeria</h1>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#index"> Home </li>
    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</li>
    <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you just need to put the color in the <header style="background-color:#D3D3D3;">

Comment: This works to a degree but aren't you supposed to do all the styling in CSS to minimise all of it in the actual html?

Also this still covers the logo.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?

you are seeing gap between header and navbar -- this is beacause the `h1` inside the `header` had default `margin`, remove that, give `padding` instead. Also remover `br`s after `header`.
Change your `.header h1` `css` to

```
.header h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 40%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
  margin: 0;
}
```

What do you mean by **stop the colour from going over the image** ?

```css
.header img {
  float: left;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 40%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
  margin: 0;
}
.headerContainer {
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav{
 width: 95%;
 margin: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter",Georgia,Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: inline;
 height: 40px;
 width: 19.925%;
    float: left;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.nav li:last-child{
 border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>The Clay Oven Pizzeria</title>
 </head>
 <header>
        <div class="headerContainer">
  <div class="header">
   <img src="images/pizzalogo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
   <h1> The Clay Oven Pizzeria</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#index"> Home </li>
    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</li>
    <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the grey area to go down past the nav bar?

Comment: you mean background color to completed `body` ?

Comment: then give it to `body` tag instead of `.header h1`

Comment: Agh no sorry, I mean would I be able to put the colour a few pixels below the nav bar?

Comment: you can just set height as you wish :
<header style="  background-color:#D3D3D3; height:300px">

Comment: keep `header` and `navbar` in a div with `padding-bottom` and give `background-color` to it